# Liferay Spring set autocommit false

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, liferay, persistence

Is there a way to turn off the autocommit for Spring in Liferay 6 running in Glassfish for all entities?

I need this for keeping a copy of the old model for auditing purposes. I tried autocommit=false in the JDBC url and setting the hibernate.connection.autocommit=false in the portal-ext.properties

```
public <T extends BaseModel<T>> T auditUpdate(final T model, final BasePersistence<T> persistence)

T oldModel = null;

try {
    oldModel = persistence.findByPrimaryKey(model.getPrimaryKeyObj());
} catch (final NoSuchModelException ignored) {
    // This is an insert
}
```

moreover `oldModel == model` returns true

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the actually expected outcome, but keep in mind that Liferay does quite a bit of caching - thus you might think you're accessing the database, but in fact you're just getting served with objects from cache. Thus there are many more levels and I'm not sure if you're attacking on the right level.

Liferay (EE) has an Audit plugin that you might want to use, also you can have ModelListeners or override the service implementations with auditing functionality. What you should use depends on how much of auditing you want to do.

Keep in mind that too much auditing can easily add a huge performance burden to your portal - so you should choose (and limit) the audited functionality carefully. It's easy to generate megabytes of audit output per mouseclick if you go with a generic "audit all" approach.